# Using AWS Glacier as back-up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup, amazon-glacier

I have a website where I serve content that is stored on an AWS S3 bucket. As the amount of content grows, I have started thinking about back-up options. Using AWS Glacier came up as a natural route.

After reading on it, I didn't understand if it does what I intend to do with it. From what I have understood, using Glacier, you set lifecycle policies on objects stored on your S3 buckets. According to these policies, **objects will be transferred Glacier and deleted from your S3 bucket** at a specific point in time after they have been uploaded to S3. At this point, the object's storage class changes to 'GLACIER'. 
 Amazon explains that, once this is done, you can no longer access the objects through S3 but "their index entry will remain as is". Simultaneously, they say that retrieval of objects from Glacier takes 3-5 hours.

My question is: Does this mean that, once objects are transferred to Glacier, I will not be able to serve them on my website without retrieving them first? Or does it mean that they will still be served from the S3 bucket as usual but that, in case something happens with the files on S3 I will just be able to retrieve them in 3-5 hours?
 Glacier would only be a viable back up solution for me if users of my website would still be able to load content on the website after the correspondent objects are transferred to Glacier.
 Also, is it possible to have objects transferred to Glacier without them being deleted from the S3 bucket?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: Does this mean that, once objects are transferred to Glacier, I will not be able to serve them on my website without retrieving them first?
No, you won't be able to serve them on your website unless transfer them from glacier to standard or standard_IA class, which is taken 3-5 hours. Glacier is generally used to archive cold data like old logs which is accessed in rare condition. So if you need real-time access to the object, Glacier isn't a valid option for you.

Comment: Is it possible to backup the S3 buckets to Glacier manually (e.g. programmitcally but not using lifecycle mgmt)?  Then he'd be able to leverage Glacier for backups and not suffer deletions from S3 bucket?